# Binding rating value to radiobuttons in Angular using ngChecked

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

I'm trying to bind values from an object to stars (radiobuttons):

```
<form id="ratingsForm">
  <div class="stars">
    <input type="radio"  #rating="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="x.rating" [checked]="x.rating >= 1" name="star" class="star-1" id="star-1" />
    <label class="star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
    <input type="radio"  #rating="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="x.rating" [checked]="x.rating >= 2" name="star" class="star-2" id="star-2" />
    <label class="star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
    <input type="radio"  #rating="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="x.rating" [checked]="x.rating >= 3" name="star" class="star-3" id="star-3" />
    <label class="star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
    <input type="radio"  #rating="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="x.rating" [checked]="x.rating >= 4" name="star" class="star-4" id="star-4" />
    <label class="star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
    <input type="radio"  #rating="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="x.rating" [checked]="x.rating >= 5" name="star" class="star-5" id="star-5" />
    <label class="star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
    {{x.rating}}
    <span></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

----Edited:
I think this should work fine as I saw in various examples on the Internet, but it displays blank stars, which means no binding.

Any solutions to make it work?

Comment: You can try with `[checked]` instead of `[ngChecked]`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: Thanks, I edited it, and used checked instead. Also I added ngModel. No errors now, but it is not displaying the colored rating, which means it is not binding.

Answer (score 0):

I presume x.rating is something which is getting dynamically. In any case ngChecked only takes expression which return true and false. A better way would be to go with a model driven also known as reactive approach. On the surface it looks like a normal approach but behind it follows Observable approach. Anything which gets changed at the back end is propagated immediately. Go through this blog to understand more of it:

https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

And
For the solution of what you are trying to achieve, you can refer to this example:

http://embed.plnkr.co/mWhYtc2nf8hSHFbLWlEx/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare each input variable in the template with the same name with the #-notation. When working with forms like these you should consider using angulars reactive form classes that let you create models for forms that let you bind it much easier from the template.

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

You can then use it in HTML as

```
<div formGroup=“rating”>
    <input type="radio" value=“1” formControlName=“star”>
    <input type="radio" value=“2” formControlName=“star”>
    <input type="radio" value=“3” formControlName=“star”>
    <input type="radio" value=“4” formControlName=“star”>
    <input type="radio" value=“5” formControlName=“star”>
</div>
```

and in TS:

```
rating = new FormGroup({
   star: new FormControl(1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A few details make your case special:

- The radio buttons are not mutually exclusive; several of them can be checked at the same time
- A radio button is checked not only if the rating matches its value, but also if the rating is higher
- Clicking a checked button can change the rating, even if the checked state does not change

Therefore:

- The radio buttons cannot share the same name (you can also use check boxes)
- I don't see how to use `ngModel` in that situation

You can try to make it work without `ngModel`; binding the `checked` property and the `click` event instead, as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12vyfc).

```
<div class="stars">
  <input type="radio" [checked]="x.rating >= 1" (click)="x.rating = 1" name="star1" ... />
  <input type="radio" [checked]="x.rating >= 2" (click)="x.rating = 2" name="star2" ... />
  <input type="radio" [checked]="x.rating >= 3" (click)="x.rating = 3" name="star3" ... />
  <input type="radio" [checked]="x.rating >= 4" (click)="x.rating = 4" name="star4" ... />
  <input type="radio" [checked]="x.rating >= 5" (click)="x.rating = 5" name="star5" ... />
  ...
</div>
```